# dns spoofing with scapy client timingout

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, dns, scapy

Consider this simple python dns spoofer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
from scapy.all import *
port = 53

def handle(payload):
    data = payload[0]
    src_ip = payload[1][0]
    src_port = payload[1][1]
    print("-" * 10 + " Incoming "  + "-" * 10)
    a = DNS(data)
    a.show2()
    output = IP(dst=src_ip,  chksum = 0)/ UDP(sport=53, dport=src_port) / DNS(id=a.id, qr=1, opcode=a.opcode, aa=1, tc=0, rd=1, ra=1, z=0, ad=0, cd=0, rcode=0, qdcount=1, ancount=1, nscount=0, arcount=0,qd=DNSQR(qname=a[DNS].qd.qname, qtype=a[DNS].qd.qtype, qclass=a[DNS].qd.qclass), an=DNSRR(rrname='cnn.com', rdata='192.168.1.100'), )
    print("-" * 10 + " Output "  + "-" * 10)
    output.show2()
    send(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # create a socket object
    s.bind(("", port)) 
    while True:
        payload = s.recvfrom(1024)
        handle(payload)
```

I would run it from sudo (so I can bind to udp port 53):

```
$ sudo python3 -i ./dns_python.py
```

However my requests to it are timing out:

```
$ host cnn.com 127.0.0.1
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I need help to figure out how to spoof successfully:

Some more details:

```
$ sudo python3 -i ./dns_python.py 
---------- Incoming ----------
###[ DNS ]### 
  id        = 59652
  qr        = 0
  opcode    = QUERY
  aa        = 0
  tc        = 0
  rd        = 1
  ra        = 0
  z         = 0
  ad        = 0
  cd        = 0
  rcode     = ok
  qdcount   = 1
  ancount   = 0
  nscount   = 0
  arcount   = 0
  \qd        \
   |###[ DNS Question Record ]### 
   |  qname     = 'cnn.com.'
   |  qtype     = A
   |  qclass    = IN
  an        = None
  ns        = None
  ar        = None

---------- Output ----------
###[ IP ]### 
  version   = 4
  ihl       = 5
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = 76
  id        = 1
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 64
  proto     = udp
  chksum    = 0x0
  src       = 127.0.0.1
  dst       = 127.0.0.1
  \options   \
###[ UDP ]### 
     sport     = domain
     dport     = 36774
     len       = 56
     chksum    = 0xb87f
###[ DNS ]### 
        id        = 59652
        qr        = 1
        opcode    = QUERY
        aa        = 1
        tc        = 0
        rd        = 1
        ra        = 1
        z         = 0
        ad        = 0
        cd        = 0
        rcode     = ok
        qdcount   = 1
        ancount   = 1
        nscount   = 0
        arcount   = 0
        \qd        \
         |###[ DNS Question Record ]### 
         |  qname     = 'cnn.com.'
         |  qtype     = A
         |  qclass    = IN
        \an        \
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]### 
         |  rrname    = 'cnn.com.'
         |  type      = A
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 0
         |  rdlen     = 4
         |  rdata     = '192.168.1.100'
        ns        = None
        ar        = None

.
Sent 1 packets.
```

I see packets when I watch from a  ngrep -d lo '' src or dst port 53 window. Any help would much appreciated!

Comment: If you are using scapy to dissect the packet, you may also want to use it to directly receive the packets. You could replace the entire loop by `sniff(prn=handle)` where handle would accept the already-dissected packet as an argument

Answer (score -1):

**Scapy does not work with 127.0.0.1 or on the loopback interface**

http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html

The loopback interface is a very special interface. Packets going through it are not really assembled and disassembled. The kernel routes the packet to its destination while it is still stored an internal structure. What you see with tcpdump -i lo is only a fake to make you think everything is normal. The kernel is not aware of what Scapy is doing behind his back, so what you see on the loopback interface is also a fake. Except this one did not come from a local structure. Thus the kernel will never receive it.

In order to speak to local applications, you need to build your packets one layer upper, using a PF_INET/SOCK_RAW socket instead of a PF_PACKET/SOCK_RAW (or its equivalent on other systems than Linux):

Comment: Wrong. Scapy does work with 127.0.0.1 and with the loopback interface. You quoted a page in the Q&A of the Troubleshooting page!